# Paste function in wps writer

Tags: windows-10, text-editors

I have just installed the WPS Writer program on windows and I have a basic question: why is the "paste" function not working? I can copy stuff but I can only paste by clicking "keep text only"; the regular "paste" command does nothing. In particular, the ctrl-v shortcut does not work and this is very annoying

Comment: I think there's a low chance you'll find other users of WPS Writer out here. Maybe you can contact WPS support? officesupport@wps.com